# Cannot play MP4 videos in Chrome and IE on ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html, iis

everyone.

I've got an ASP.net page that's supposed to play a particular video, but it only works in Firefox.  This page uses HTML5 video tags to play it.

Here's the exact HTML that the page generates.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MMI Video Play</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html
        {
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="generalVideoPlay.aspx?v=Henry-Ford-Event" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTIwNDExNTQ2NDFkZItFaUIKUt6Do1YOY8xI/g5wUtS6O2VGMvVfY/eqc5NF" />
</div>

<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; margin-top: 12px;">
    <video width='720' height='480' controls>
        <source src="files/video/Henry-Ford-Event.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src='files/video/Henry-Ford-Event.ogv' type="video/ogg" />
        <!-- fallback to Flash: -->
        <object width='720' height='480' type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="files/resources/player.swf">
            <param name="movie" value="files/resources/player.swf" />
            <param name="flashvars" value='file=../video/Henry-Ford-Event.mp4&image=poster.jpg' />
            <!-- fallback image. note the title field below, put the title of the video there -->
            <img src="images/noVideo.jpg" width="720" height="480" alt="No Video Playback" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
        </object>
    </video>
    <div style="visibility: hidden; margin-top: 14px; font-family: Arial; margin-top: 18px;"><strong><a href='files/video/Henry-Ford-Event.mp4'>Download Video</a></strong></div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the list of things I've tried/learned.

- It is absolutely pointing to the correct source because I can download and play the video from the link it provides.
- It has nothing to do with MIME types on IIS because OGV is not there and it work in Firefox.  Furthermore, I added MP4 to IIS and it still doesn't work.
- I've copy-pasted the above HTML into an HTML file (as opposed to an aspx file) I made on my local drive and it works just fine.

I really don't know what else to try.  The thing that kills me is that the HTML works in and of itself, but when I run it from the site it gives nothing.  I'll greatly appreciate an answer to this problem.

EDIT:  I've also found this page (http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2011/11/03/making-html5-video-work-with-iis-express.aspx) and can safely say that, while the symptoms are the same, I am not finding a stream/octet MIME type issue.

Comment: Have you tried lower case html in your DOCTYPE declaration? I don't know if FF is less picky on that than IE and Chrome. The correct XHTML5 definition would be lower case I believe. Just a wild guess. :D

Comment: @Tombala I have tried your suggestion of making it lowercase.  Unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: @user2429616 Witch version of IE did you try?

Comment: @VitorCanova It was IE 9 on 64-Bit Windows 7.

Comment: @user2429616 In Dev tools (F12) witch is the browser mode and document mode it uses when you open this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to get this sorted out.  Ultimately I gave up on doing pure HTML5 and went for JWPlayer which works quite well.  Though, even when I started using that, I *still* couldn't get things to work perfectly.  The final piece of the puzzle was ripping the videos from the DVD again using Handbrake and checking the "Web Optimized" option.  That, combined with JWPlayer, has completely solved my issue.  I hope this helps out some other poor soul who has to do Web video work.